# Transferring RSS feed into string

Tags: iphone, string, twitter, rss, uilabel

I have a RSS feed set up for my iPhone application that takes news updates from twitter and adds them to a UITable. This works great, but I was thinking of making the information scroll across the top of the screen instead. So here is my problem: I can't figure out how to convert the feed into text labels I can use on my news scroll. Does anyone know how?

Comment: If you can put it in a table, you can put it in a label, surely? UITableViewCells use labels to display their contents. Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Nathan Constance can you please elaborate ?